# How do you delete roles in Parse.com using Cloud Code

Tags: parse-platform, cloud, acl, role

How do you delete roles in Parse.com using Cloud Code? I checked: https://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Role.html, and it doesn't document any destroy method.

I am creating a role for every group of members, and I'd like to get rid of the role when the group is destroyed. What is the correct way of doing so?

Comment: Looks like destroy() worked, but I'll keep this question around for a while to see whether there is a better/prescribed way of destroying roles.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen:

```
role.getUsers().remove(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me:

```
const roles = await new Parse.Query(Parse.Role).find();
await Parse.Object.destroyAll(roles, {useMasterKey: true}};
```

Answer (score 0):

I played around with this for hours before getting it to work by fluke (no thanks to deficient and incorrect documentation)...

This is architecturally incorrect but the only way I could hack it together was using async function with await + promise... I do not understand Parse's weird mechanics sometimes. It's a love & hate relationship!

```
// Get user to delete object
    let userToDeleteObject = await new Parse.Query(Parse.User)
      .equalTo('objectId', userToDelete)
      .find({useMasterKey: true});
      // Remove user from group role
      let roleDeleteQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
      roleDeleteQuery.contains("name", groupName);
      roleDeleteQuery.first({useMasterKey: true})
      .then(function(roleObject) {
        roleObject.relation("users").remove(userToDeleteObject);
        roleObject.save(null, {useMasterKey: true});
      });
```